# How to type state and dispatch for useReducer - TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am currently seeing this error with my current setup.

> Type '({ team: string | null; } | { team: string | null; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | Dispatch<...>)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'State': teamts(2739)
>   index.d.ts(290, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps'

My code is below, if any more detail is required let me know.

actions.ts

```
export const setTeam = (team: string | null) => ({
  type: 'SET_TEAM',
  team,
});
```

reducer.ts

```
export const initialState = {
  team: null,
};

type State = {
  team: string | null;
};

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext<State | null>(null);

export const reducer = (state: State, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_TEAM:
      const team = action.team;
      return {
        ...state,
        team,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return ( 
    // error with state and dispatch here
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
        ...App code
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Team.tsx

```
import { GlobalContext } from './reducers';
import { setTeam } from './actions';

const Team = () => {
   const [, dispatch] = React.useContext(GlobalContext);

   return <span onClick={() => dispatch(setTeam('LFC'))}>LFC</span>
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `setTeam()` is used or why that should matter in this context...

Comment: You are typing the context as an object with `team` property but you are passing an array with state and dispatch as elements

Comment: @PatrickRoberts updated the question

Comment: @AsafAviv so can you explain how I should type this? Sorry, I am not sure

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to pass the state and the dispatch through context you have to type it on the context, you can go with just this line but if you want type safety read further

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext<[State, React.Dispatch<any>]>([
  { team: null },
  () => {},
])
```

You can change the `<any>` inside `React.Dispatch` to your action types if you want type safety for actions, you would also need to type the action inside the reducer

```
enum TeamTypes {
  SET_TEAM = 'SET_TEAM',
  REMOVE_TEAM = 'REMOVE_TEAM',
}

type State = {
  team: string | null
}

export const initialState: State = {
  team: null,
}

type SetTeamAction = {
  type: typeof TeamTypes.SET_TEAM
  team: string
}

type RemoveTeamAction = {
  type: typeof TeamTypes.REMOVE_TEAM
}

type TeamActionTypes = SetTeamAction | RemoveTeamAction

export const setTeam = (team: string): TeamActionTypes => ({
  type: TeamTypes.SET_TEAM,
  team,
})

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext<
  [State, React.Dispatch<TeamActionTypes>]
>([{ team: null }, () => {}])

export const reducer = (state: State, action: TeamActionTypes): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TeamTypes.SET_TEAM:
      const { team } = action
      return {
        ...state,
        team,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}></GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for this,  but after adding 
`const GlobalContext = React.createContext<[State, React.Dispatch<any>] | null>(null)` 
getting an error 

`This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'State | Dispatch<any>' are callable.`

Comment: @peterflanagan type the `type` inside of your action creators with the types on the `enum` `export const setTeam = (team: string | null) => ({
  type: TeamTypes.SET_TEAM,
  team,
});
`

Comment: @peterflanagan can you make a sandbox or update the question with your current code and from the line you get the error?

Comment: the error is coming from `{() => dispatch(setTeam('LFC'))}`

Comment: @peterflanagan check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-easley-d6wwq) against your code and tell me whats wrong

Comment: I am not sure, one thing is the version of ts is different and also updated the ts config but the code sandbox still works. One thing, why don't you have to add `| null` at this line as my ts setup complains about this also `const GlobalContext = React.createContext<[State, React.Dispatch<TeamActionTypes>]>(null)`

Comment: there's no `strict` compiler option in the sandbox and you probably have it, just  add `null` to it and try to upgrade typescript and see if it solves the problem. other than that you will have to reproduce it in a sandbox and i can take a look

Comment: i read a lot about not using enums in a typescript environment. How would you handle the enum TeamTypes as a type in that context?